# How to implement the curl --header in C++ (specifically for tdameritrade)

Tags: c++, curl

I recently started to write a C++ program to GET and POST data from/to tdameritrade through their api. I am new to cURL. tdameritrade has put up some guides for their apis. They do provide with simple commands that can be run from a terminal or through python. e.g. 
curl -X GET --header "Authorization: Bearer accesscode" "https://api.tdameritrade.com/v1/marketdata/GOOGL/pricehistory?apikey=userkey&periodType=day&period=2&frequencyType=minute&frequency=5".

And this command would return me the price history of the stock (GOOGL) in this case.
I am trying to implement the same command using libcurl library in ubuntu. Here is a snapshot of my code:

```
#include "curl/curl.h"

int main(){
const std::string myheader("Authorization: Bearer accesscode"); 
const std::string url("https://api.tdameritrade.com/v1/marketdata/GOOGL/pricehistory?apikey=userkey&periodType=day&period=2&frequencyType=minute&frequency=5");

CURL* curl = curl_easy_init();
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
.
.
.
curl_easy_perform(curl);
curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &httpCode);
curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

}
```

But I do not know how to implement the --header part into the curl options. Please advice. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to add header, you need to use

```c
struct curl_slist *headers=NULL;
headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Authorization: Bearer accesscode");
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
```

Reference:
https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/httpcustomheader.html